# Can I have an action which runs several methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have this in my controller:

```
def something
end

def email
end

def house
end
```

I want to create an action that runs all of the action something, email and house

```
def runall
Run email, something and house
end
```

How is it done?

Comment: Maybe it's not the best idea, if that actions gonna generate html for user. Describe more what this actions do, maybe you can replace them with observer class or delayed_job?

Comment: actually I am trying to create a delayed job. I thought I should put my tasks in my controller and then use  handle_asynchronously :runall. Can you help me with this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661998/rails-help-creating-a-delayed-job-from-a-rake-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def runall
  [:something, :email, :house].each{|a| send(a)}    
end
```

Using [Object#send](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999)

This is all assuming these are some sort of private helpers, rather than actual controller actions that are called to render a view etc. Otherwise I don't suggest doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Just for vocabulary's sake:

- you've had great answers to the following question: "can I have an action which runs several methods"
- an action is linked to a view so it's non-sense to execute several actions at once