# Rails delayed job not working

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

My delayed job is not working. I am trying to create an background task for a rake file using a delayed job that should run every 15 minute. I have copied my rake tasks in my rake file and set them in my controller as methods. I need an delayed job because heroku only makes a cron every 1 hour.

Here is my Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

require 'delayed_job'
require 'Mechanize'
require 'pp'


protect_from_forgery

def iqmedier
          agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
          agent.get("http://www.iqmedier.dk")
          form = agent.page.forms.first
          form.submit

          agent.page.link_with(:href => "/Publisher/Stats").click

          form = agent.page.forms.first
          form.submit

          @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')[-2]

          @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0]})
          if @existing.nil?
              Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2], :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
          elsif @existing.dato != Date.today
          Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => Date.today, :unik_klik => 0, :klik => 0, :unik_vis => 0, :vis => 0, :leads => 0, :ordre => 0, :cpc => 0, :earn => 0)
          else
            @existing.update_attributes!(:unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
          end
  end
 def euroads
        agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
        agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'}
        agent.get("http://www.euroads.dk")
        form = agent.page.forms.first
        form.submit
        @month = Date.today.strftime("%m").to_s
        agent.get("http://www.euroads.dk/system/index.php?showpage=showstat&show=overview&month=#{@month}&year0=2011&day=1&month=#{@month}&year=2011&day1=31&month1=#{@month}&year1=2011&fk_campaign=&fk_survey=&fk_track=&fk_pool=&columns1=1&columns2=2&columns4=4&columns14=14&columns5=5&columns6=6&columns7=7&columns8=8&columns9=9")

        @stats =  agent.page.search('table.ea').search('tr')

        @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0]})
        if @existing.nil?
            Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Euroads', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
        elsif @existing.dato != Date.today
          Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Euroads', :dato => Date.today, :unik_klik => 0, :klik => 0, :unik_vis => 0, :vis => 0, :leads => 0, :ordre => 0, :cpc => 0, :earn => 0)
        else
          @existing.update_attributes(:unik_klik => @stats[1], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[3], :vis => @stats[4], :leads => @stats[5], :ordre => @stats[6], :cpc => @stats[7], :earn => @stats[8])
        end
  end

def mikkelsen
        agent = Mechanize.new
        agent.get("http://affilate.mikkelsenmedia.dk/partnersystem/mylogins.php")

        form = agent.page.forms.first
        @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')

        @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @stats[0] })
        if @existing.nil?
            Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Mikkelsen', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[3], :klik => @stats[3].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[1], :vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[4], :ordre => @stats[9], :cpc => @stats[3], :earn => @stats[5])
        else
            @existing.update_attributes(:virksomhed => 'Mikkelsen', :dato => @stats[0], :unik_klik => @stats[3], :klik => @stats[3].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[1], :vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[4], :ordre => @stats[9], :cpc => @stats[3], :earn => @stats[5])
        end
   end
def orville
        agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
        agent.get("https://dk.orvillemedia.com")

        form = agent.page.forms.first
        form.submit
        @dato = Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_s
        @month = Date.today.strftime("%m").to_s
        @day = Date.today.strftime("%d").to_s
        @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')

        @existing = Reklamer.find(:first, :conditions => {:dato => @dato})
        if @existing.nil?
            Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Orville', :dato => @dato, :unik_klik => @stats[2], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[1], :vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[3], :ordre => '0', :cpc => (@stats[5] == '-' ? 0 : @stats[3]), :earn => @stats[6])
        else
          @existing.update_attributes(:virksomhed => 'Orville', :dato => Date.today, :unik_klik => @stats[2], :klik => @stats[2].to_i, :unik_vis => @stats[1], :vis => @stats[1], :leads => @stats[3], :ordre => '0', :cpc => (@stats[5] == '-' ? 0 : @stats[3]), :earn => @stats[6])
        end
   end

def runall
  [:iqmedier, :euroads, :mikkelsen, :orville].each{|a| send(a)}    
end
handle_asynchronously :runall, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }
```

When I run rake jobs:work it starts but is not working the runall job of

Comment: i don't see a delay call anywhere @_@

Comment: Where should the delay call go?

Comment: What do you mean by GET. The screen scraping is POST. Run all should be all the methods, iqmedier, euroads, orville and mikkelsen

Comment: delay is the one that adds a job to your jobs db

Comment: Where should delay go in my controller?

Comment: I have tried [:iqmedier, :euroads, :mikkelsen, :orville].each{|a| send(a)}. delay   -  It dont work

Comment: make sure your using this version of delayed job for Rails 3: git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git (branch 'rails3'), why are you requiring it in your Application controller? Use the gemfile and this isn't necessary.

Comment: I am using the Rails 3 version of delayed_job. I have also added delayed_job to my gem file.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what you're trying to achieve here... What method is called using a browser? If it's any other than runall method, then there's no any reason to believe that it'll be run in background. Please explain what you're trying to do, the full flow that you anticipate.

Comment: I am trying to create an background task that runs my screenscraping methods (iqmedier, euroads og mikkelsen) every 15 minutes. I am trying to move my original screenscraping rake file to a controller to create an delayed job that should run every 15 minute. I cannot use a cron job because heroku, only run cron jobs every 1 hour. ( I am sorry for my bad english)

Comment: So, all of the methods besides runall should be private, then, after starting the worker, you should request the runall using a browser or curl.

Comment: How do I request runall using a browser or curl?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then you should have the following:

`scraper.rb`

```
require 'mechanize'

class Scraper
  def perform
    [:iqmedier, :euroads, :mikkelsen, :orville].each{|a| send(a)}
  end

  def iqmedier
    # some code
  end

  def mikkelsen
    # some code
  end

  def orville
    # some code
  end

end
```

in your controller:

```
require 'delayed_job'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def runall
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(Scraper.new, :run_at => 5.minutes.from_now)
  end
end
```

For adding jobs from outside of rails, you can write something similar and then run it with rails runner:

```
require 'scraper'
Delayed::Job.enqueue Scraper.new
Delayed::Job.enqueue Scraper.new, :run_at => 15.minutes.from_now
Delayed::Job.enqueue Scraper.new, :run_at => 30.minutes.from_now
Delayed::Job.enqueue Scraper.new, :run_at => 45.minutes.from_now
```

Comment: I have put the runall in my application controller and the scraper.rb myapproot/lib/jobs. When I run rake jobs:work a worker starts but nothing really seems to happen. It is just stuck in Starting worker

Comment: Did you browse with your browser to the URL which should enqueue the job, eg. Something/runall ?

Comment: When I browse the action runall I get a nameerror: uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Scraper

Comment: You need to require 'scraper'.

Comment: Now it is saying Template is missing? Why do I need a view?

Comment: C'mon. Please start by reading some basic tutorial about Ruby on Rails. In any case, if you just want to redirect, you can use redirect_to, otherwise you'll need a view template.

Comment: I really fail to understand what you're trying do do, as you started with controller, therefor I assumed that you want to trigger the scraping using a browser. If you just want periodic scraping, just use cron.

Comment: I cannot use Cron because it runs only every hour on heroku. I want the screenscraping to run every 15 minute

Comment: Run once per hour and schedule 4 jobs - one for now, one in 15 minutes, one in 30 minutes and one in 45 minutes.

Comment: Can you show my an example of to create this with a cron job and a rake file

Comment: omg.. upvote for bothering to try, Roman. tzown, worst code I've seen in a long time. The Q is poorly written and messy, wasting a lot of good peoples time.

Comment: Roman how should I run the cron job every 15 minute on heroku. I have read this but dont see how to run a cron job every 15 minute. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run code every X minute/hour, than you don't need delayed_job for that. That would be kind of overkill and over engineered. Just use this code here:

```
    until 2 < 1 do 
        if Time.now.min % 15 == 0

            puts "Execute your code here!"

            if Time.now.min % 15 == 0
                sleep(60)
            end
        end
    end
```

Put the code into Rakefile, make a task out of it and deploy it on a heroku worker dyno. That will work. Here is a complete tutorial for that: http://robert-reiz.com/2012/06/12/cron-jobs-on-heroku/.

For that solution you even don't need Herokus Cron or Scheduler Add-On. And you don't need any additional GEMs like delayed_job. Pragmatic solution. Keep it slim ;-)

Comment: If you need a more sophisticated scheduler for cron tasks, take a look to Rufus and clockwork. I guess that is a better fit for your use case than delayed_job.